# Zero and negative value rows removal and hourly mean for Time Series Data

Tags: r

I have a time series data which consist of 1440 readings/observations with 8 ( BB%, BC1,BC2,BC3,BC4,BC5,BC6,BC7) variables. This dataset is per minute data of 24 hours.

If any of the columns i.e  BC1,BC2,BC3,BC4,BC5,BC6,BC7 has zero or a negative value in it then I want to remove that entire row from BC1,BC2,BC3,BC4,BC5,BC6,BC7 columns including BB% and take out mean of columns.

Also, I want to take out the hourly mean of this data.

```
Date        Time      BB% BC1 BC2 BC3 BC4 BC5 BC6 BC7
18/06/2019  0:00:00   23  769 642 679 505 514 554 534
18/06/2019  0:01:00   24  770 0   682 643 667 474 509
18/06/2019  0:02:00   22 -732 720 667 725 645 576 468
18/06/2019  0:03:00   19  781 785 673 653 0   656 665
18/06/2019  0:04:00   17  809 748 0   700 677 552 596
18/06/2019  0:05:00   21  726 756 717 579 646 536 613
```

Comment: `dat[rowSums(dat[,c(4:10)] < 0) < 1,]`

Comment: Do you need `df %>% summarise_at(vars(BC1:BC7), ~mean(.[. > 0]))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can read the data first.

```
df <- readxl::read_excel('10.10.2019.xls', sheet = '20191010', skip = 4)
```

and then remove rows where 0 is present and calculate `mean` for selected columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(AB1:AB7), all_vars(. > 0)) %>%   
  summarise_at(vars(AB1:AB7), mean)
```